# how to write a single query for displaying a value for multiple inputs

Tags: mysql, sql

```
   select value from students where coll_Id=1
   select value from students where coll_Id=2
   select value from students where coll_Id=3
   select value from students where coll_Id=4
   select value from students where coll_Id=5
   select value from students where coll_Id=6
   select value from students where coll_Id=7
   select value from students where coll_Id=8
   select value from students where coll_Id=9
   select value from students where coll_Id=10
```

How to write a single query for the above statement.

Comment: select value from students where coll_Id between 1 and 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select value from students where coll_Id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

EDIT: // see question comment by @t-clausen.dk

If you're always dealing with ranges you could use

```
select value from students where coll_Id between 1 and 10;
```

which is equivalent to

```
select value from students where coll_Id >= 1 and coll_id <= 10;
```